# Explanation to how the length between 2 centers is adjusted as angle changes

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, angle

I'm working on a project, that takes 2 similar elements and allows you to adjust the angle of the center-line by grabbing the right side and moving it up or down.

In this scenario, lets use the key:
circles are 20mm each
centerpoint to centerpoint of the circles is 120mm total. Making the distance between the outer edges 100mm.
[image]

If i wanted to ensure that the distance of the 2 center points (call it reach), were to remain 120mm, would the right side circle ever adjust on the x-axis to ensure this? or as long as it only moves the y-axis, that reach should stay the same? If it would need to be adjusted, what function should I look into?

To get the YAxis value I am using the following:

```
circHeight / 2 * Math.tan(angle * Math.PI / 180)
```

I tried adjusting this xAxis as well, but I'm unsure if I even needed to.

```
Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * initialDistance
```

where initialDistance would be `120`.

Sorry if thats not the correct terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL DR**

Yes, for any given angle you will need to adjust the x axys.

**Intuition**

Start with the two centers aligned on the x axys. If you move the center up the new distance between the two centers will be the hypotenus of a right triangle. The old one will be one of its catethes and so it will be smaller then the new distance

**Calculation**

You can compute the coordinates of the rotated circle by using the rotation matrices. Assume the center of the left circle is the origin of a coordinates system. Let the coordinates of the right circle be $(x_c,y_c)$. Then after a rotation of an angle $\theta$ you will have
$$
x'_c= x_c \cos(\theta)-y_c \sin(\theta)
$$
$$
y'_c=x_c \sin(\theta) + y_c \cos(\theta)
$$
In your numerical example $x_c=120$ $y_c=0$